# Android - How can I create layout as per image attached for different screens?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, design-guidelines

Android - How can I create layout as per image attached for different screens?
[image: screenshot]

Comment: I think you're going to need to give some more information about the problem you're facing if you want answers

Answer (score 0):

You must make different designs and use the visibility attribute to change the designs:

```
RelativeLayout oneLayout = findViewById (R.id.one_view);
RelativeLayout otherLayout = findViewById (R.id.other_view);
oneLayout.setVisibility (View.GONE);
otherLayout.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
```

To know what design to use:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().GetDisplayMetrics ();
          int height = metrics.heightPixels;
          int width = metrics.widthPixels;
          int density = metrics.densityDpi;
```

This way you will know the width and height of the screen.
For the design you have chosen, you should read about RelativeLayout and ConstraintLayout.

Answer (score 0):

So there is one option, which is way too sophisticated and going to be fun to implement but could take forever, you draw this on a `Canvas` with all sort of paths and whatnot.

Another option is not very clever, but I think will do the trick!

**Step 1**
Split your background into squares, so that your background is a grid. Split it horizontally and vertically, like the images below.
[image][image]
Place those into containers, namely `ViewGroup`s that split the screen correctly .. maybe using weights or `ConstraintLayout`

**Step 2**
You can align your items to the edges of those backgrounds you constructed.

Just an idea :)